# Formik FieldArray Yup error validation not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

Hello I am trying to achieve error validation with Yup and Formik and I cannot figure out how to get it working with just an array of strings. There no examples of simple arrays of Formik and Yup.

I am simply trying to use the required() method to ensure the user enters at least one friend before they are allowed to press submit. For some reason I am not getting anything in my errors though.

I created a codesandbox for anyone that would like to help me.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-fire-ksbid?file=/src/App.tsx

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called your field `description` in the schema when it should be `friends`. You can also add `.min(1)` to make sure there's one. I always add `.trim()` too so empty strings aren't accepted, unless people can have friends called `"  "`.

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  friends: yup.array().min(1).of(yup.string().trim().required())
});
```